# How to properly concatenate a string received in parts?

Tags: c, sockets

I'm using sockets in C, I have a client that will send a message and the size of the message and the server that will receive this message in buffers of shorter size. The message is being sent correctly, but I'm having problems when I try to concatenate all the buffers in a single string.

The client:

```c
char *buffer = "Hello from the client you're receiving this message";
int bytes_sent;
long msgSize = strlen(buffer);
printf("Buffer Size: %ld\n", msgSize);
int msgFileSize = send(SocketFD, &msgSize, sizeof(msgSize),0);
bytes_sent = send(SocketFD, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
```

The server:

```c
char buffer[8];
ssize_t recsize;
long msgSize;
int msize = recv(ConnectFD, &msgSize, sizeof(msgSize), 0);
int total_byt = 0;
printf("Full Message Size: %ld\n", msgSize);
char full_msg[msgSize];

while (total_byt < msgSize) {
  recsize = recv(ConnectFD, (void*)buffer, sizeof buffer, 0);
  total_byt += recsize;
  strcat(full_msg, buffer);
  if (recsize < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("recsize: %d\n ", (int)recsize);
  sleep(1);
  printf("datagram: %.*s\n", (int)recsize, buffer);
}

printf("full message: %s\n", full_msg);
```

The output of the server looks like this:

```
Full Message Size: 51
recsize: 8
 datagram: Hello fr
recsize: 8
 datagram: om the c
recsize: 8
 datagram: lient yo
recsize: 8
 datagram: u're rec
recsize: 8
 datagram: eiving t
recsize: 8
 datagram: his mess
recsize: 3
 datagram: age
full message: ��9�Hello from the client you're receiving this message mess
```

Comment: initialize full_msg[0]='\0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few problems here.

1. `strlen` returns length excluding the `null` char.

   ```
   long msgSize = strlen(buffer);
   ```

   Thus you need to have 1 additional place to hold `null` char.

   ```
   char full_msg[msgSize+1];
   full_msg[0] = '\0';
   ```
2. There is undefined behavior with `strcat` as `buffer` is not `null` terminated.

   ```
   recsize = recv(ConnectFD, (void*)buffer, sizeof buffer, 0);
   strcat(full_msg, buffer);
   ```

   use

   ```
   strncpy(full_msg, buffer, sizeof buffer);
   ```
3. Finally `null` terminate the `full_msg` after loop to be sure.

   ```
   while (total_byt < msgSize) {
   ….
   }
   full_msg[total_byt] = '\0';
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your full message variable is not initialized. It is starting out with random data in it, which is causing your unexpected results. Use the following code to initialize it:

```
char full_msg[msgSize] = "";
```

Also, using `strcat` in the way you are is not safe. You must keep track of how much space is left in `full_msg` or you will have a buffer overrun situation. [`strncat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncat/) is the function that can solve this problem.

Comment: I can't initialize the char, I'm getting this error: "error: variable-sized object may not be initialized". I tried this: full_msg[0] = '\0'; and the output looks like this: "full message: Hello from the client you're receiving this message mess"

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely no point reading into a separate buffer and then concatenating that into another buffer. Just read directly into `full_msg`.

Even if you were going to append block by block, `strcat` is not the right way to do it. `strcat` needs to start by finding the current end of the output buffer, which it can only do by sequentially scanning from the beginning looking for a NUL byte. As the buffer gets more and more data, those scans get longer and longer, leading to quadratic time complexity. This particular unnecessarily quadratic append is often called a "Schlemiel the Painter" algorithm.

The scan is unnecessary because you already know where the new data should be appended, since you carefully keep track of how many bytes you've already read. So each successive block should be placed `total_byt` bytes past the beginning of the buffer. (That is, at location `full_msg+totalbyt`.) You also know how long the data to append is, so you can use `memcpy` to put the newly-read chunk in the right place.

Uding `memcpy` will also avoid the problems which will occur if data can contain NUL bytes. (Since `strcat` returns immediately when it encounters a `NUL`, your current code will not work on messages which do include NUL.)

Note that`recv` does **not** NUL-terminate the input received, so your `strcat` will also do the wrong thing if the `recv` doesn't fill the buffer (and it only works with the buffer as written because it happens to be the case that

There is at least one other problem with your code: nothing guarantees that `recv` will stop reading at the end of a message, since the sockets library doesn't know where TCP messages end. (UDP message endpoints are marked, but you can't receive a UDP message in multiple chunks.) Again, since you keep track of the number of bytes read, and you know the length of the message (once you've read that data, at least), you can easily work out what the maximum number of bytes to read is.